# Custom Theme missing from drupal theme folder

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, drupal-theming

I have themed my Drupal site with the Bootstrap framework. I have set it as default and now I want to move over to an editor and write some code for my home-page. However, I can't seem to find the theme folder in the path that it's supposed to be in. All other default theme folders are present though. So ideally I can't work with my theme from the folder end, rather I'm forced to maneuver everything from the browser. Did I probably miss something?

Comment: where do you expect your theme?

Comment: Ideally it should be in the path sites/all/themes/Bootstrap - but I cant see the Bootstrap folder

Comment: How you "themed" your site? What did you install? A module?

Comment: When you say "with the bootstrap framework", do you mean the bootstrap project at https://www.drupal.org/project/bootstrap? Or did you download the more general framework like at http://getbootstrap.com/? If the former, you're going to actually want to create a subtheme of it, or if you ever update the base theme, you're changes will be wiped.